# Browser (Chrome, Safari etc.) continues to show the old HTML website, even after updates

Tags: html, caching, browser, atom-editor, updating

I've built a website in HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 4 etc. etc. through Atom. Every time I make changes and upload the new version to the hosting platform (HostPresto in my case) browsers load the previous (presumably cached) version. I know browsers use the cached data for loading and data efficiency etc. However, my aim is to force any browser to reload from scratch, ONLY if some part of the website has changed. How do I do this?

I've seen some answers on stackoverflow to similar queries over the years, where people have suggested using code in the website header to effectively wipe the cookies and cached data each time it is loaded. I don't want to do this all the time, since more often than not, no changes will be made and my website will be less efficient.

My hosting provider has said that it would help if I upload ALL website files each time only a bit has changed. I tried this today and it doesn't work - I still have to clear the cache for it to load properly.

Can anyone help me work out what to do, to get any browser to identify when changes have been made to my site, so that it will load them automatically? Thanks!

Comment: Without developing a `parser` that effectively compares your old site to the (possible) "new" site and running it on page load, I don't know how you'd do this. Even implementing that would drastically reduce performance. IMO you can either force a cache clear on page load, or manually clear it to solve this issue. :/

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion. Because you're currently building the site, once you've finished it, you should no longer need the cached data to be reset every time.  While you're developing if you use Chrome, you can empty the cache and reload at once by pressing and holding the reload button and then select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. Note you need to have the inspector opened for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I'll stick to the current 'method' of forcing the website to reload from scratch by emptying the cache. I don't want to drastically reduce performance at all!

Answer (score 2):

I've cracked my own issue, so to speak, so I thought I'd post the answer here, in-case it helps others.

Basically, I noticed that the HTML files would always reflect the latest changes. However, it was the CSS files that wouldn't. The CSS files were the culprits for loading from the browser cache.

To correct this, I have started adding versioning to my CSS files to force the browser to load the new CSS file, ONLY when the CSS is updated. it works like this:

- The name of the CSS file isn't changed. That is, and always was `styles.css`. You might call it something else.
- The old call I would make for my CSS file, in the head of the HTML file, was:   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`.
- The new call is:   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?version=1.0">`

All I have done is add `?version=1.0` to the end of the CSS file name in the HTML header. If the version number changes, the browser will load the newest version. If the version number is the same, it won't load the newest one.

I imagine this would be quite straightforward for some but since I have managed to sort it myself, I thought it might be useful to share with others. There's now no need for adding hard code into the HTML header that causes efficiency-losing reloads from scratch unnecessarily!